# I can't seem to print several lines of data in qt creator. Program overwrites all output except for the last line

Tags: c++, qt, output

My intended output: To print the time and number of bacteria for an exponential equation. I'm trying to print every data point up until time t, for instance if I'm finding the growth up until 50 hours in, I want to print the number of bacteria at time 0, 1, 2, ..., 49, 50. I am trying to have each output on a new line as well.

### So here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButtonCalc_clicked()
{
    QString s;
    double t = ui->t->text().toDouble();
    double k = ui->k->text().toDouble();
    double n0 = ui->n0->text().toDouble();

    /*double example;
    example= k;
    s = s.number(example);
    ui->textOutput->setText(s);*/

    for(int c = 0; c<t; ++c)
    {
        double nt = n0*exp(k*t);
        s = s.number(nt);
        ui->textOutput->setText(s);

    }

}
```

---

I've tried quite a few different outputs, and have also been trying to append new points to an array and print the array, but I haven't had too much luck with that either. I'm somewhat new to c++, and very new to qt.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: What kind of widget is `textOutput`?  Calls to `setText` on Qt widgets will completely replace the contents of the widget with whatever you're passing in, which is why you're only seeing the last line.

Comment: textOutput is a QTextEdit currently, which I think is suppose to be an input. But I've tried with a label and text browser as well with no luck

Also, I didn't know that with setText. it makes sense, thank you. Any functions that would do better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QTextEdit::setText` function is going to replace the contents of the text edit with the parameter you pass in.  Instead, you can use the `append` function:

```
for(int c = 0; c<t; ++c)
{
    double nt = n0*exp(k*t);
    s = QString::number(nt);
    ui->textOutput->append(s);
}
```

Note also that since `QString::number` is a static function, you don't need an instance to call it.

Alternately, you can create the string in your loop and then set it to the text edit using `setText`:

```
for (int c = 0; c<t; ++c)
{
    double nt = n0*exp(k*t);
    s += QString("%1 ").arg(nt);
}
ui->textOutput->setText(s);
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, both of those. I tried append before, but I didn't have the QString:: thing going on. After four hours of trying this, you saved me. I gave you a check mark thing, I'd upvote but I have a new account.